# MongoDB logging and authentication

Tags: mongodb

I am trying to get a mongoDB working with authentication, using both Java and PHP drivers.  I've added user roles to the mongoDB but haven't yet turned on authentication (so clients can login with usernames and passwords, but they don't have to, and user roles are not yet enforced).

To check that everything is working, before actually turning authentication on, I've been looking at the `mongod.log` file.  I see things like:

```
2015-11-17T08:47:19.052+0000 I NETWORK  [initandlisten] connection accepted from ###:### #158126 (46 connections now open)
2015-11-17T08:47:19.960+0000 I ACCESS   [conn158126] Successfully authenticated as ### on ###
```

But.... I also see quite a few connections *without* the "ACCESS" line.  However, when cross referencing with logs of the clients, it seems they *are* trying to connect with authentication.

> What can be going on?

Is it perhaps the case that the ACCESS log only occurs if some database action is taken?  So, e.g. if a client connects but doesn't try to read or write, would I not see the 2nd line?

Comment: Try raising the verbosity level for the access control component. I bet you will see much more detail in the log. https://docs.mongodb.org/v3.0/reference/configuration-options/#systemLog.component.accessControl.verbosity

Comment: Stackoverflow is a Q&A site for software developers. But database permission management and configuration is a topic for database administrators. I nominated your question for migration to https://dba.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is it perhaps the case that the ACCESS log only occurs if some database action is taken?

At least for the JAVA driver I'm using, "yes" is the answer.  I ran a test, connecting, requesting a DB and collection, but doing nothing more, and no authentication check is triggered.  It's only when you try to read/write that the authentication happens.